# flex 4 - aligning/positioning the controls dynamically by ignoring invisible controls

Tags: layout, flex4

I am using flex's layout feature to avoid the coding to align/position. How ever, it looks like though I hide (visible = false) any object, flex treats it as exists and doesn't re-align or re-position the controls as I expected.

I think, **I can achieve it if I can add/remove the controls dynamically but I dont want to do that.**

Does flex has the feature to ignore the invisible control and align the visibile controls only?

Below is the scenario

I have a  with two  in it. Either "any one" or "both" the buttons will be visible depending on the logic. No problem if I have to show both the buttons because they will be properly aligned. But if I have to show only one, the positions remain same as if both are visible.

Is there any way exists to re-align the controls when I hide/show something dynamically? That **without having to add/remove**

```
    <s:Group width="100%" id="pricesGroup">

        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout gap="5"/>
        </s:layout>

        <s:Button id="btnCoins" label="{coins.toString()}" chromeColor="#94E749"/>

        <s:Button id="btnFlux" label="{flux.toString()}" chromeColor="#3B8DC7"/>

    </s:Group>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also mark the component out of the layout

```
<s:Group includeInLayout="false" />
```

if not, the component will keep reserved some space in the layout.